# Visual Studio Code V1.65.2 terminal fuzzy screen

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual Studio code, and I trapped in a strange problem need help.

After install VS Code smoothly. lunch it and soon I found the terminal windows looks like this:
[image]The content of terminal window looks fuzzy both in powershell and cmd mode.

I try many ways hope to solve this problem but trapped for two days still the same. Anyone please help.
VSCode runs well on my another laptop but it was send for part replacement.

Here list all the methods i tried: (all follow by relaunch VSCode and open terminal)

- switch between cmd/Powershell
- turn on/off terminal window.
- update Windows to latest version
- uninstall user version. install All-user version (VSCodeSetup-x64-1.65.2.exe)
- uninstall VS ALL-user version, reinstall user version(VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.65.2.exe)
- install language pack Chinese(Traditional), switch betwen English/Chinese language settings.
- install powershell from VsCode marketplace
- change terminal setting from integrated to external. (C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe)
- install powershell 7.2
- update powershell to version 7.2.2

Note: C/C++ extersions V1.9.7 from VSCode marketplace installed.

Update 2022/3/31: I try to install older version (visual-studio-code-1-37-1-64-bit.exe). The first launch after installation, terminal looks OK!. Close it and launch again, the terminal became fuzzy again. Hope this gives you some help to solve this problem.

My Windows version:

- Version   Windows 10 Pro, x64
- version   21H2
- Install at    ‎2022/‎3/‎19
- OS build      19044.1620
- Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0

My hardware:

- Labtop: Lenovo W520
- CPU:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2860QM CPU @ 2.50GHz
- (RAM) 16.0 GB

I appreciate any advice.

Regards,

Stanley Hsu

Answer (score 0):

I found a post that solves this fuzzy terminal problem. [post link here](https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_44378370/article/details/106843338)

Here's how:

1. Go to your shortcut which lunches VS code. My shortcut is at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
   [image: shortcut location]
2. Right-click on the icon and select Property. Select the second TAG from the left.
3. Locate target(T), it should look like this: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
4. Add `--disable-gpu` at the end of the path. It should look like this:
   [image: add parameter here]
5. Click Apply and OK, exit the property window.
   That's it. After the above steps, the terminal block in my VS Code is normal.
   [image: Clear terminal]
   Hope this helps anyone who gets into the same problem.